# Fast way to put 2 lists of String arrays into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm currently using 2 lists of strings to create a datatable. I'm wondering there if there is any faster way than using 2 foreach loops there?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("id");
table.Columns.Add("parentId");
table.Columns.Add("value");

List<MyData1> parents = new MyDataHandler.GetAllParents(); // Has id, name
List<MyData2> childs = new MyDataHandler.GetAllChilds(); // has id, parentId, name

// Fill the list with all parents
foreach (MyData1 p in parents)
{
    table.Rows.Add(new String[] {p.id, null, p.name});
}

// Fill the list with all childs
foreach (MyData2 c in childs)
{
    table.Rows.Add(new String[] {c.id, c.parentId, c.name});
}
```

Like mentioned before I'm wondering if there is any faster way to do this (as table.Rows has no addRange method) as that seems quite overcomplicated and slow to me.

As note here:
ParentId in MyData 2 references the id in MyData1.  Both lists come from the database with

```
public List<MyData1> GetAllParents()
{
    using (MyEntity entity = new MyEntity())
    {
        return (from e in entity.MyData1 select new MyData1 { id = e.id, name = e.name }).ToList();
    }
}

public List<MyData2> GetAllChilds()
{
    using (MyEntity entity = new MyEntity())
    {
        return (from e in entity.MyData2 select new MyData2 { id= e.id, name = e.name, parentId = e.parentId}).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a really faster code but an easier to read one.
like creating a function to convert List to DataTable.

Comment: Are you sure your code does what you expect?

YOu are iterating over all the MyData1's in childs, but childs is a list of MyData2....

Comment: @JakobOlsen tnx for pointing that error out. Copy and paste error (had to rename the fields and classes before posting here and that error just crept in tnx)

Answer (score 0):

That variant not faster but maybe simplier to use:

```
var parents = new MyDataHandler.GetAllParents()
    .ToDataTableModel(p => p.Id, p => null, p => p.Name);
var childs = new MyDataHandler.GetAllChilds()
    .ToDataTableModel(c => c.Id, c => c.ParentId, c => c.Name);
var table = parents.Concat(childs).ToList().ToDataTable();
```

You only need 2 extensions and 1 new class:

```
public class DataTableModel
{
    public int Id;
    public int? ParentId;
    public object Value;
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<DataTableModel> ToDataTableModel<TSource>(this List<TSource> sourceList, Func<TSource, int> getId, Func<TSource, int?> getParentId, Func<TSource,object> getValue)
    {
        var tempList = new List<DataTableModel>();
        var query = from entry in sourceList
                    select new DataTableModel
                    {
                        Id = getId(entry),
                        ParentId = getParentId(entry),
                        Value = getValue(entry)
                    };
        return query.ToList();
    }

    public static DataTable ToDataTable<TSource>(this List<TSource> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(TSource).GetFields())
        {
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, 
                Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.FieldType) ?? prop.FieldType);
        }
        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (var prop in typeof(TSource).GetFields())
            {
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(entry) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

ADDED: Fixed some mistakes. Just finished testing. Works fine.